# Marionette router not triggering controller method on route

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, browserify

I'm trying to upgrade an application from Marionette 1.* > 2.4.2. The biggest part of this change is shifting away from Marionette modules to using Browserify/Watchify with CommonJS style modules.

I've hit a roadblock while trying to get a Router/Controller up and running. No error is thrown, but for some reason my routes arent triggering my controller methods.

doc_router.js:

```
var $ = require('jquery')
    , _ = require("underscore")
    , Backbone = require("backbone")
    , Marionette = require("backbone.marionette")
    , App = require("../../app.js")

var Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({

    appRoutes: {
        "docs": "listDocs"
    }
});

// Map to controllers

var API = {

    listDocs: function () {
        console.log("listDocs") // Doesnt log to console
        App.DocApp.List.Controller.listDocs();
    }
};

// Update the URL when a controller event
// that requires it is triggered, then call
// appropriate controller via API.

App.on("docs:list", function () {
    App.navigate("docs");
    API.listDocs();
});


// Initialize router when app starts

App.on("before:start", function () {
    console.log("History started? ", Backbone.History.started);
    console.log("Initializing router...")
    new Router({
        controller: API
    });
});

module.exports = Router;
```

app.js:

```
var $ = require('jquery')
    , _ = require("underscore")
    , Backbone = require("backbone")
    , Marionette = require("backbone.marionette")


var App = new Marionette.Application();

App.addRegions({ 
    mainRegion  : "#main-region",
    modalRegion : "#modal-region"
});

App.on("start", function () {
    if (Backbone.history) {
        console.log("Application starting...");
        var fetchingCurrentUser = App.request("entities:current-user");

        $.when(fetchingCurrentUser).done(function (current_user) {
            App.currentUser = current_user;
            console.log("Starting history...");
            Backbone.history.start();

            console.log("History started? ", Backbone.History.started);
        }); 
    }
});

module.exports = App
```

main.js:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var App = require('./app.js');

App.Entities = _.extend({}, 
    require("./entities/doc.js"), 
    require("./entities/user.js")
);

// DocsApp
App.DocsApp = {
    "Router": require("./apps/doc/doc_router.js"),
    "Reader": {
        "Controller": require("./apps/doc/reader/doc-reader_controller.js"),
        "Views": require("./apps/doc/reader/doc-reader_views.js")
    },
    "List": {
        "Controller": require("./apps/doc/list/doc-list_controller.js"),
        "Views": require("./apps/doc/list/doc-list_views.js")
    }
};

App.start();
```

Judging by my console logs it doesn't seem like I'm starting Backbone.history before creating the router. Really pulling my hair out on this one... Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**

Using Backbone.Router appears to work (below). Why isn't Marionette.AppRouter working?

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "": "listDocs",
        "docs": "listDocs",
        "docs/:doc_id" : "readDoc",
        "docs/:doc_id/edit" : "editDoc"
    },

    listDocs: function () {
        console.log("listDocs") // Logs to console
        // App.DocApp.List.Controller.listDocs();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up switching to backbone.base-router, which allowed me to specify a controller since the Marionette AppRouter apparently has issues with Browserify.

Comment: "AppRouter apparently has issues with Browserify" do you have any more info on that?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue and it seems that the routes are conflicting with the Express routes. My application was working correctly on my Tomcat app. server. But ever since I switched to Express all the routes stopped being executed. Also had it working when using Backbone router.

Answer (score 1):

Marionette extends Backbone's built-in router, so if you want `router.navigate` to trigger the route function, [you'll have to pass the option *trigger* like this](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate):

```
router.navigate('docs', {trigger: true});
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should be more clear in the question. I am navigating to "docs" in the browser address bar. Shouldnt need to router.navigate("docs"). Although I have tried this just to help debug the situation and it still does not work.